# Proof that the data structure used to store the unmatched men in Gale Shapley Algorithm has no effect on the solution.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I understand that no matter which man proposes first, the Gale Shapley algorithm gives the same best perfect match result. Is there a scientific explanation to prove that the data structure used to implement and store the free men has no effect on the final answer?

Comment: Why would it? It's an algorithm; the data structure type doesn't have anything to do with the correctness of the solution (unlike, say, its efficiency) any more than whether the answer is written in English or French. Typically in such situations, you posit a data structure that has can read certain kinds of data, write certain kinds of data, etc; how those features are implemented is irrelevant.